# How can I impersonate Bob without creating a new session

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis, man-in-the-middle

Good morning,

I've been struggling with this protocol for the last few days and I'm out of ideas now. The goal is to impersonate Bob by just modifying or dropping packages. The attacker(me) is a Proxy that is between the clients and the servers so any messages are first sent to me and I send relay them to the servers.

I have thought about setting up two sessions and do a Reflection but then the session key in the second message wouldn't be the same and the task description also says that it is possible by just modifying the messages.[image]

Can you guys please help me out ?

Edit: I should add that K_AB is a long term key and K_'AB is the session key